# Python: Plotting against one variable of a function

Tags: python, oop, matplotlib

I've been dinking with this for a while now:

I have a function that relies on five (5) variables before it can be solved (Black-Scholes). After I've solved the price for this one instance of BS, I'd like to create a range of the differing inputs (say, time) and plot them against the corresponding outputs (the solution, with all other variables held constant).

So hopefully I'd be plotting something like

```
class BS

    def __init__(self, args)
        self.a = float(args[0])
        self.b = float(args[1])
        self.c = float(args[2])
        self.d = float(args[3])
        self.e = float(args[4])
    ...
    ...
    the math
    ...
    ...
```

Now, I can create an instance of that class that holds a method for calculating the price from T or time.

```
def price(self)
   'math that only requires T'
    return price
```

So, I'd only need to run BS.price() and could output something like

```
t = range(T-200, T+200, 1)

prices = [BS.price() for x in t]
rhos = [BS.rho() for x in t]
vegas = [BS.vega() for x in t]
parities = [BS.parity() for x in t]


pylab.plot(prices,t)
pylab.plot(rhos,t)
pylab.plot(vegas,t)
pylab.plot(parities,t)
```

if the only variable for price is the time. Is there a better way to observe a single-variable dependence with python? I would prefer R, but it's not up to me.

Thanks for your help!

EDIT: I don't know how to use list comprehensions when the time variable is undergoing math operations like math.sqrt() and scipy.cdf(). Is there a way to do this? I know how to build the function relying on variable t, a float. How would I input a list of values into math.sqrt() or scipy.cdf()? Thanks for the help!

Comment: It's not clear where in your list comprehension the updated time variable gets passed to your class. Once you create an instance of BS, then ever after BS.price() will be a constant determined by the parameters. Under your design, you'd need to create new instances of BS for each different time. And in that case, wouldn't it be better to make the BS class just accept a list of times as an argument, along with fixed other parameters? Note also that you're not creating a BS object in your example code, so unless `price` is a static method (with a decorator) you cannot call it this way.

Comment: I don't know how to use list comprehensions when the time variable is undergoing math operations like math.sqrt() and scipy.cdf(). Is there a way to do this? I know how to build the function relying on variable t, a float. How would I input a list of values into math.sqrt() or scipy.cdf()? Thanks for the help!

Comment: If your function takes several arguments, one option is to make a lambda where all but time are fixed. Assuming you have `my_price_func(a,b,c,d, time)` ... then just define `fixed_args = lambda t: my_price_func(a=self.a, b=self.b, c=self.c, d=self.d, time=t)` Now you can call `[fixed_args(t) for t in time_range]`, all within the class definition. This is a bit of a messy solution because your chosen class design is not a good way to encapsulate an algorithm like Black Scholes. I suggest first becoming a bit more familiar with python first. Ask some simplified example Q on list comprehensions.

Answer (score 1):

> I don't know how to use list comprehensions when the time variable is undergoing math operations like math.sqrt() and scipy.cdf(). Is there a way to do this? I know how to build the function relying on variable t, a float. How would I input a list of values into math.sqrt() or scipy.cdf()?

There are few options to consider:

- Python generators allow you to generate results on the fly as you iterate through collections/list of values. Here is a very good discussion:
  http://wiki.python.org/moin/Generators
- Python's map and reduce functions allow you to apply functions (e.g. sqrt) to each element in the list and with reduce you can reduce each of the results of some operation to the list into a single value (Check 2.1 "mapping the list"):
  http://www.siafoo.net/article/52